# How to convert visual selection from unicode to the corresponding character in vim command?

Tags: vim, unicode, neovim

I'm trying to convert multiple instances of Unicode codes to their corresponding characters.

I have some text with this format:

> U+00A9

And I want to generate the following next to it:

> ©

I have tried to select the code in visual mode and use the selection range '<,'> in command mode as input for i_CTRL_V but I don't know how to use special keys on a command.

I haven't found anything useful in the manual with :help command-mode . I could solve this problem using other tools but I want to improve my vim knowledge. Any hint is appreciated.

Edit:
As @m_mlvx has pointed out my goal is to visually select, then run some command that looks up the Unicode and does the substitution. Manually input a substitution like `:s/U+00A9/U+00A9 ©/g` is not what I'm interested in as it would require manually typing each of the special characters on every substitution.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is - what is the input of i_CTRL_V? It takes no input at all. If that satisfy you I could show you the substitute command that solves your problem.

Comment: I guess you want to select a block of the code in visual mode.  Then what?  As @kosciej said, a substitution would be natural, something like `:s/U+00A9/U+00A9 ©/g`.  But that would be boring, if there are many different Unicode examples.  So I guess you want to visually select; then run some command that looks up the Unicode, and does the substitution automatically?  That actually sounds interesting, so I will watch for answers.  (But please edit your question to be clear.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any hint is appreciated.

Here are a whole lot of them…

1. `:help i_ctrl-v` is about insert mode and ranges matter in command-line mode so `:help command-mode` is totally irrelevant.
2. When they work on text, Ex commands only work on *lines*, not arbitrary text. This makes ranges like `'<,'>` irrelevant in this case.
3. After carefully reading `:help i_ctrl-v_digit`, linked from `:help i_ctrl-v`, we can conclude that it is supposed to be used:

   - with a  lowercase `u`,
   - without the `+`,
   - without worrying about the case of the value.

   So both of these should be correct:

   ```
   <C-v>u00a9
   <C-v>u00A9
   ```
4. But your input is `U+00A9` so, even if you somehow manage to "capture" that `U+00A9`, you won't be able to use it as-is: it must be sanitized first. I would go with a substitution but, depending on how you want to use that value in the end, there are probably dozens of methods:

   ```
   substitute('U+00A9', '\(\a\)+\(.*\)', '\L\1\2', '')
   ```

   Explanation:

   - `\(\a\)` captures an alphabetic character.
   - `+` matches a literal `+`.
   - `\(.*\)` captures the rest.
   - `\L` lowercases everything that comes after it.
   - `\1\2` reuses the two capture groups above.
5. From there, we can imagine a substitution-based method. Assuming "And I want to generate the following next to it" means that you want to obtain:

   ```
   U+00A9©
   ```

   you could do:

   ```
   v<motion>
   y
   :call feedkeys("'>a\<C-v>" . substitute(@", '\(\a\)+\(.*\)', '\L\1\2', '') . "\<Esc>")<CR>
   ```

   Explanation:

   - `v<motion>` visually selects the text covered by `<motion>`.
   - `y` yanks it to the "unnamed register" `@"`.
   - `:help feedkeys()` is used as low-level way to send a complex series of characters to Vim's input queue. It allows us to build the macro programatically before executing it.
   - `'>` moves the cursor to the end of the visual selection.
   - `a` starts insert mode after the cursor.
   - `<C-v>` + the output of the substitution inserts the appropriate character.

   That snippet begs for being turned into a mapping, though.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something like that feedkeys function. The snippet doesn't work with trailing spaces at least in command-line, without them it joins the substrings correctly and works like a charm. Also, the <CR> is not needed when used from command line. (All of this on neovim 0.6)

Answer (score 2):

In case you would like to just convert unicodes to corresponding characters, you could use such nr2char function:

```
:%s/U+\(\x\{4\}\)/\=nr2char('0x'.submatch(1))/g
```

Brief explanation

```
U+\(\x\{4\}\) - search for a specific pattern (U+ and four hexadecimal characters which are stored in group 1)
\= - substitute with result of expression
'0x'.submatch(1) - append 0x to our group (U+00A9 -> 0x00A9)
```

In case you would like to have unicode character next to text you need to modify slightly right side (use `submatch(0)` to get full match and `.` to append)

Answer (score 2):

In case someone wonders how to compose the substitution command:

```
'<,'>s/\<[uU]+\(\x\+\)\>/\=submatch(0)..' '..nr2char(str2nr(submatch(1), 16), 1)/g
```

The regex is:

- word start
- Letter "U" or "u"
- Literal "plus"
- One or more hex digits (put into "capture group")
- word end

Then substituted by (`:h sub-replace-expression`) concatenation of:

- the whole matched string
- single space
- character by UTF-8 hex code taken from "capture group"

This is to be executed in Visual/command mode and works over selected **line** range.